# Estimator with algorithm about graphs

Tags: statistics, graph-theory, algorithms

Consider an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ representing the social network of friendship/trust between students. We would like to form teams of three students that know each other. The question is to decide whether the network allows for enough such teams, without checking all the triples of graph $G$. For this reason, we use random sampling to design an efficient estimator of the number of connected triples. We partition the set of node triples into four sets $T_0,T_1,T_2$, and $T_3$. A node triple $v1,v2,v3$ belongs to:

- $T_0$ iff no edge exists between the nodes $v1,v2$, and $v3$,
- $T_1$ iff exactly one of the edges $(v1,v2)$, $(v2,v3)$, and $(v3,v1)$ exists,
- $T_2$ iff exactly two of the edges $(v1,v2)$, $(v2,v3)$, and $(v3,v1)$ exist,
- $T_3$ iff all of the edges $(v1,v2)$, $(v2,v3)$, and $(v3,v1)$ exist.

$|T_3|$ denotes the number of connected triples in the graph that is the quantity we need to estimate. Consider the following algorithm:

• Sample an edge $e=(a,b)$ uniformly chosen from $E$

• Choose a node $v$ uniformly from $V \setminus(a,b)$

• if $(a,v)∈E$ and $(b,v)∈E$ then $x=1$, else $x=0$

Let $x_1, x_2, . . . x_s$ be the outcomes of $s$ independent executions of the algorithm. Show that

$\frac{1}{s}$ $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^s x_i \frac{|E|(|V|-2)}{3}$
is an estimator of $|T_3|$.

I have to do this exercise in a university course of algorithms. The problem is I have no skills about statistics and the course doesn't give anything about this arguments, and I don't know neither how to start to prove this. Could someone give me help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exercise is wrong in asking you to show that something is an estimator. There's nothing to show there, since you can use whatever quantity you want as an estimator for $|T_3|$. It's not part of the definition of an estimator that it bears any particular relationship to the estimated quantity. There are specific properties of an estimator, such as being unbiased, efficient or sufficient, which can be proven, but you can’t “show” that something is an estimator of $|T_3|$.

A reasonable guess at what they mean is that this is an *unbiased* estimator of $|T_3|$, i.e. that the expected value of this estimator is the true value of $|T_3|$.

To show that this is the case, first consider the simpler procedure of uniformly randomly selecting any of the $\binom{|V|}3$ potential triangles between any $3$ vertices. In this case, we'd expect to select a triangle of three existing edges with probability

$$
\frac{|T_3|}{\binom{|V|}3}\;,
$$

so

$$
\frac1s\sum_{i=1}^sx_i\binom{|V|}3
$$

would be an unbiased estimator of $|T_3|$. Note that this procedure is equivalent to first uniformly randomly selecting a pair of vertices (i.e. a potential edge) and then uniformly randomly selecting a third, different vertex. That suggests a more efficient approach: Since the contribution to the estimator from the sum will be $0$ if we select a pair of vertices that aren’t connected by an edge, we can instead uniformly randomly select an existing edge. The result is the procedure specified in the exercise. We're now ignoring the zero contributions from vertex pairs not connected by an edge; we're still uniformly sampling the remaining contributions from vertex pairs connected by an edge, but by a factor

$$
\frac{\binom{|V|}2}{|E|}
$$

more often than before. Thus the expected value of $x_i$, i.e. the probability of sampling a triangle, is now

$$
\frac{|T_3|}{\binom{|V|}3}\cdot\frac{\binom{|V|}2}{|E|}=\frac3{|E|(|V-2|)}\cdot|T_3|\;,
$$

and so

$$
\frac1s\sum_{i=1}^sx_i\frac{|E|(|V-2|)}3
$$

has expected value $|T_3|$ and is thus an unbiased estimator of $|T_3|$.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand some things:

- what is the meaning of $\frac{\binom{|V|}{2}}{|E|}$ ?

- I understood what is the result of the multiplication, but why if you ignore the zero contributions does the probability of sampling a triangle become equal to that multiplication?

Comment: @bruce_springsteen: Originally, you're sampling each pair of vertices with probability $1/\binom{|V|}2$ (since there are $\binom{|V|}2$ such pairs). Now, you're only sampling those pairs that are connected by an edge, of which there are $|E|$. The probability of sampling any particular vertex pair that's connected by an edge is therefore now $1/|E|$. Thus, you've changed the probability of sampling any particular vertex pair that's connected by an edge by the factor $\binom{|V|}2/|E|$.

Comment: Ok, thanks!
I understood how the probability of finding any couple of nodes changes if we consider only the couples connected by an edge, but why this change also affects the probability of finding a triangle by the "exact" same factor? Is there a theorem or something that I am missing?

Comment: @bruce_springsteen: You don't need a theorem for that: You're selecting either a connected pair of vertices and a triangle (probability $p_1$) or a connected pair of vertices and not a triangle (probability $p_2$) or an unconnected pair of vertices (probability $p_3$). If you ignore the unconnected pairs of vertices and sample only from the first two options, the probabilities are renormalized to $\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}$ for connected pair and triangle and $\frac{p_2}{p_1+p_2}$ for connected pair and no triangle.

Comment: The ratio between the original probability $p_1$ and the renormalized probability $\frac{p_1}{p_1+p_2}$ is the normalization factor $\frac1{p_1+p_2}$, the reciprocal of the probability of selecting a connected pair of vertices.

Comment: Thanks, now it is all clear!!
By the way, since you're so kind maybe you can help me with this too (same problem, another question) : https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119152/number-of-executions-of-the-algorithm-with-probability-about-graphs